# Java Agent in Domino designer not signed after import

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I imported a java-agent into an iNotes application using DXLImporter. The agent seems to be signed using my User Id. When imported into the host application, I am receiving the fowllowing error in domino designer:

Could not open the editor: Error - Document is not signed..

I tried to configure the agents before exporting them as DXL. I also configured my DXLImporter like this:

```
    dip.ReplaceDBProperties = False 
    'Don't import any documents
    dip.DocumentImportOption = DXLIMPORTOPTION_IGNORE 
    dip.ReplicaRequiredForReplaceOrUpdate = False 
    'Use ACL of host DB
    dip.ACLImportOption =  DXLIMPORTOPTION_IGNORE
    dip.DesignImportOption =  DXLIMPORTOPTION_REPLACE_ELSE_CREATE
```

I would like to ignore my signature or to **programmatically** sign the stuff with the User Id of the host application if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the sign method of NotesDatabase- Class to sign the whole database, or just some specific elements or even one specific element. Check out [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SIGN_METHOD_DB.html) for the designer help for is method.

Here is an excerpt of the linked site:

---

Call notesDatabase.Sign( [ documentType% ] [ , existingSigsOnly ] [ , nameStr$] [ , nameStrIsNoteID ] )

**Parameters**

*documentType%*

Integer. Optional. One of the following constants.

DBSIGN_DOC_ACL (64) signs the ACL
DBSIGN_DOC_AGENT (512) signs all agents
DBSIGN_DOC_ALL (32767) (default) signs all elements except data documents' active content
DBSIGN_DOC_DATA (1) signs all data documents' active content (hotspots)
DBSIGN_DOC_FORM (4) signs all forms
DBSIGN_DOC_HELP (256) signs the "About Database" and "Using Database" documents
DBSIGN_DOC_ICON (16) signs the icon
DBSIGN_DOC_REPLFORMULA (2048) signs the replication formula
DBSIGN_DOC_SHAREDFIELD (1024) signs all shared fields
DBSIGN_DOC_VIEW (8) signs all views

*existingSigsOnly*

Boolean. Optional.

True to sign only elements with existing signatures.
False (default) to sign all elements.

*nameStr*

String. Optional. Programmatic name or note ID of a single design element. If this parameter is not specified, all design elements of type parameter 1 are signed.

*nameStrIsNoteID*

Boolean. Optional.

True if parameter 3 represents a note ID.
False (default) if parameter 3 represents a programmatic name.

---

For your example it would be something like:

```
call db.sign(DBSIGN_DOC_AGENT, False, "NameOfYourAgent", False)
```